# Извлечь URL из href с помощью XPath

Tags: html, xpath

Не получается из `href` извлечь содержимый *URL* с помощью *XPath.*

Пробовал так:

```
//a[contains(@id, 'MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_lnkAddress')]//@href/text()
```

Но когда подставляю функцию `text()`, *XPath* не видит…

Вот *HTML* код:

```html
<a
id="MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_lnkAddress_0"
class="address"
href="/Section-8-housing-in-Cincinnati-OH/1-bedroom-1-bathroom-rental-Apt/4887044"
>3050 Mickey Ave 4, Cincinnati, OH 45204</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
//a[starts-with(@id, "MainContentPlaceHolder_properties_lnkAddress")]/@href
```

Comment: да вы правы этот вариант как xpath работает. Но саму ссылку из href выделить в виде текста не удается.. Может вы знаете как это сделать ?

Comment: Что значит «саму ссылку»?  Атрибут `href` содержит в себе гиперссылку на ресурс.  Если вы хотите часть этой гиперссылки получить, вам нужно парсить её парсером _URL._  _XPath_ тут уже ни при чём.